# IntelliJ shortcut for selecting multiple whole lines

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

So, for example, if the cursor is in the middle of a line pressing `SHIFT` and the down arrow twice would select three entire lines rather than from the current cursor position to the same position 2 lines below.

Comment: Maybe not exactly that helpful to you  but, if nothing is selected, copy and cut will copy and cut the line you are on. I like that feature.

Comment: Yep, use that one a lot too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such action at the moment, feel free to [submit a feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA).

Comment: It's not that important, just saves pressing HOME twice. Thx.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the Ctrl-W featuer in IntelliJ. It's not exactly the same as what you describe, but it is an ok alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is to duplicate (copy/paste) the whole multiple lines, then probably there is an alternative shortcut that I use.

Just make a selection that partially cover lines that need to be duplicate. Then invoke command 'Duplicate Lines' (or Ctrl+D).